# GPG Encryption fails intermittently on same command - results in no such file or directory

Tags: encryption, command-line, gnupg

The following command is run from the Windows command line and it works sometimes, but it does not in other occasions.

```
GPG --recipient "my.puclic.key@recipient.com" --output "MyEncryptedFileName.txt.PGP" --encrypt "MyTestDocument.txt Working Directory: \\myServer\myfolderName\
```

The directory and file name exist, but it seems like GPG can't find them.  I have also tried the command as..

```
GPG --recipient "my.puclic.key@recipient.com" --output "MyEncryptedFileName.txt.PGP" --encrypt "MyTestDocument.txt Working Directory: \\myServer\myfolderName\"
```

and

```
GPG --recipient "my.puclic.key@recipient.com" --output "MyEncryptedFileName.txt.PGP" --encrypt "MyTestDocument.txt Working Directory: \\myServer\myfolderName"
```

but keep getting an error:

> "can't open 'MyTestDocument.txt Working Directory:\\myServer\myfolderName\': No such file or directory
>   gpg MyTestDocument.txt Working Directory: \\myServer\myfolderName\: encryption failed: No such file or directory

In prior occasions this same command worked fine.

Comment: Are these really the commands you're executing? As the quotes don't match.

Comment: Yes... I changed the file names and path to simplify.  When it works it only has a double quote at the beginning of the file name to encrypt as... --encrypt "MyTestDocument.txt etc...     With no quotes on the end.

Comment: I'm not so sure about whether these are valid file names in Windows (actually, I think they're not). Does `\\myServer\myfolderName\MyTestDocument.txt` work as expected?

Comment: Here is the actual GPG command...
GPG --recipient "it.security.ftp@insco-st.com" --output "CONTRACT_LAB_20140609.txt.PGP" --encrypt "ExportFileTemplate2.txt Working Directory: \\corpfs04\ExternalInternalEvents\
Does that help?

Comment: I don't think there anything like that syntax to give the working directory. Either cd in there before running the command (and omit all that `Working directory: ...` stuff), or give it as a full path like I proposed in the previous comment.

Comment: It works if I map the drive... like  --encrypt "z:\myTestDocument.txt
But it also works as listed before if a specific user runs the command.  It seems it may have more to do with the type of user access to the drive.  However the Working Directory option does work, but I can't find references on its syntax anywhere online.